# Reduce memory warnings and improve memory managemet

Tags: java, android, memory

I am doing an app that take data from service and represents it in a graph. App runs Ok but in logcat appears a lot of GC_FOR_ALLOC messages.

Is there anyway to reduce this messages? any function or something?

this is the logcat:

```
02-17 17:40:37.427: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 275K, 2% free 16994K/17300K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-17 17:40:39.397: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 516K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:39.987: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-17 17:40:40.287: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-17 17:40:40.577: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:41.117: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:42.687: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-17 17:40:45.887: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-17 17:40:47.187: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
02-17 17:40:47.457: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:47.737: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-17 17:40:48.817: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:49.097: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:49.417: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-17 17:40:49.687: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-17 17:40:49.967: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-17 17:40:50.237: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-17 17:40:50.507: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 4% free 16993K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:50.777: D/dalvikvm(30112): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 4% free 16994K/17540K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-17 17:40:51.257: D/dalvikvm(772): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 972K, 44% free 31389K/55540K, paused 69ms, total 69ms
```

thanks

Comment: Try the solutions given here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517908/why-so-many-gc-for-alloc-in-a-simple-app

Answer (score 0):

GC_FOR_ALLOC simply means that there was not enough memory to complete the allocations tasks and hence more space needs to be allocated through GC.

When Android starts, it starts with a small heap and this grows as applications grow and consume memory. Before memory is increased, GC_FOR_ALLOC is run which is standard expected behavior. It's not necessarily because your app is consuming too much memory.

From your logcat output, it doesn't seem like anything strange is happening. If you want to turn off these messages, they have a log level of DEBUG. Any log level higher than that and you will not see them.