# android - GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6346K, 7% free , paused 143ms, total 143ms

Tags: android, performance, garbage-collection, android-mapview

I'm developing an offline mapView using OSMdroid Library. My tilesource loads the tiles but renders quit steadily. But the fact is in my log messages, I keep getting this error:

`GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6346K, 7% free , paused 143ms, total 143ms`

I'm not sure how to debug this? Any ideas, do I have any memory leaks?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517908/why-so-many-gc-for-alloc-in-a-simple-app/20523690#20523690

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is not an error, but an information that Garbage collector has run.

If you are seeing a lot of those, it might mean that you are making many allocations or have little memory. You should try to improve your program's memory performance.

There is a good source information about investigating RAM consumption in Android:

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

There is also a document about general strategies for managing your memory consumption in Android:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: nice explanation for new commers ;)

Comment: The second document was very useful&enlightening to me.

Comment: @gruszczy I'd one more msg popping, `05-12 11:51:06.581: I/Choreographer(6837): Skipped 392 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Comment: Well, you are doing some heavy processing in your Activity thread. You need profile your application and probably move some code to a separate thread or to a service.

Comment: @gruszczy how do I profile my application? I've heard about DDMS method profiling, but I've not understood correctly. Any tips to understand the same?