# Meaning of logcat dalvikvm error message

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I can't find them documented anywhere. So what does the values in this Logcat error message mean:

```
06-28 14:59:53.172: E/dalvikvm(32679): 32679(...) stat: (e)  393  5941KB / (c)    0     0KB / (a)   27    69MB / (h)   730KB  2668KB  1937KB
```

I should additionally mention that after this message I got this:

```
06-28 14:59:53.172: D/dalvikvm(32679): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2050K, 65% free 4916K/13892K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
```

Comment: @Selvin Because I deleted this post. And because beside this logcat message it has nothing to do with a textview or string parsing or a bufferedreader! And because I did not target this concrete message in my deleted question.

Comment: @matcauthon please refer fadden's answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508981/android-gc-for-alloc-freed-6346k-7-free-paused-143ms-total-143ms

Answer (score 2):

From Android Documentation :

```
D/dalvikvm: <GC_Reason> <Amount_freed>, <Heap_stats>, 

<External_memory_stats>, <Pause_time>
```

Example :

```
D/dalvikvm( 9050): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2049K, 64% free 3571K/9991K,

external 4703K/5261K, paused 2ms+2ms
```

All fields name are self-explainatory, but some points to note :

- freed 2049K - this is amount of live object **freed** by **GC** in this run
- 64% free 3571K/9991K - **64% of 9991K which = 6494K amount is free** and **36% is live object size**