# Progress dialog dismiss too late

Tags: java, android

When i caclulate distance between route on **async loadview**. result is work normally. but when completed calculation, progress dialog can't close directly. i have read [Why so many GC_FOR_ALLOC in a simple app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508981/android-gc-for-alloc-freed-6346k-7-free-paused-143ms-total-143ms/) . But i still confuse with thats conclusion, becouse my result has completed.

```
    private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<LatLng>, Integer, ArrayList<String>>
{
      LatLng firs_point;
      ArrayList<LatLng> objek_sync;

      public LoadViewTask(LatLng firs_point, ArrayList<LatLng> objek_sync){
         this.firs_point=firs_point;
        this.objek_sync=objek_sync;
      }
    //Before running code in the separate thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

        //Create a new progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        //Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar 
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL );
        //Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        //Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please wait...'
        progressDialog.setMessage("Harap Tunggu!");
        //This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //This dialog isn't indeterminate
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        //The maximum number of items is 100
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        //Set the current progress to zero
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        //Display the progress dialog
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    //The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<LatLng>... params) 
    {
        /* This is just a code that delays the thread execution 4 times, 
         * during 850 milliseconds and updates the current progress. This 
         * is where the code that is going to be executed on a background
         * thread must be placed. 
         */
        ArrayList<LatLng> objekarray= new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        objekarray=objek_sync;
         final Integer[] idx=new Integer[objekarray.size()] ;
         final double[] data=new double[objekarray.size()] ;
        try 
        {
            //Get the current thread's token
            synchronized (this) 
            {
                //Initialize an integer (that will act as a counter) to zero
                int counter = 0;
                //While the counter is smaller than four
                    int proc=0;
                    for (int i=0; i< objekarray.size();i++)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        proc=(counter*100)/60;
                        /*DirectionJsonPharser _distance= new DirectionJsonPharser();
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(firs_point, atmarray.get(i) );*/              
                        //txtv.setText(_distance.distance_count(url));

                        idx[i]=i;
                        data[i]=(double) distance_AtoB(firs_point, objekarray.get(i));
                    /*  data[i]= Double.parseDouble(_distance.distance_count(url));*/
                        publishProgress(proc);
                        this.wait(1);
                    }



                    Arrays.sort(idx, new Comparator<Integer>() {
                        @Override public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {
                            return Double.compare(data[o1], data[o2]);
                        }
                    });


            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int cn=60;int cntr=0;int proc1=0;
        ArrayList<String> ner=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> qr=new ArrayList<String>();
        try 
        {
            //Get the current thread's token
            synchronized (this) 
            {

                      for(int j=0;j<idx.length;j++){
                          cntr++;
                          proc1=cn + (cntr*100)/30;
                        globalvariable ak= new globalvariable();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idx[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        objek=ak.koneksi("master.php","status=" + idx[j] + ""); 
                        this.wait(10);
                        jArray= new JSONArray(objek);                   
                        JSONObject json_data=null;                      
                        json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        if(j==0){

                            qr.add(json_data.getString("nm"));
                            ner.add(json_data.getString("kd"));
                        }else{
                            int ceksama=0;
                            for(int sem=0;sem<ner.size();sem++)
                            {
                                if(ner.get(sem).equals(json_data.getString("kd"))){
                                    ceksama=1;
                                    }
                            }
                            if(ceksama==0){
                                qr.add(json_data.getString("nm"));
                            ner.add(json_data.getString("kd"));
                            }
                        }

                      }
                      //objek=qr;

            } 
       }
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        publishProgress(100);

        return qr ;

        //return null;
    }

    //Update the progress
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
    {
        //set the current progress of the progress dialog
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    //after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) 
    {

        //close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        gps_mode=null;
        Spinner spin_jalur= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_jalur);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, result);
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin_jalur.setAdapter(adapter);




        //initialize the View

    }   
}
```

this is my log cat...

```
   08-30 09:19:05.660: D/dalvikvm(6631): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 313K, 54% free 4673K/10055K, external 1304K/2106K, paused 31ms
08-30 09:19:06.050: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
08-30 09:19:06.050: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
08-30 09:19:06.050: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
08-30 09:19:06.050: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(6631): (thUse=28) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
08-30 09:19:06.060: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(6631): (thUse=28) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
08-30 09:19:06.060: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
08-30 09:19:06.060: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
08-30 09:19:06.060: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(6631): (thUse=28)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
08-30 09:19:06.480: D/dalvikvm(6631): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 312K, 54% free 4674K/10055K, external 1304K/2106K, paused 33ms
08-30 09:19:06.860: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(6631): (thUse=28) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(6631): (thUse=28) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(6631): (thUse=28) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
08-30 09:19:06.870: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=28) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(6631): (thUse=28)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
08-30 09:19:07.300: D/dalvikvm(6631): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 312K, 54% free 4674K/10055K, external 1304K/2106K, paused 37ms
08-30 09:19:07.640: W/System.err(6631): org.json.JSONException: Value 500 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at com.example.ankara.MainActivity$LoadViewTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:241)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at com.example.ankara.MainActivity$LoadViewTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-30 09:19:07.650: W/System.err(6631):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

This is my koneksi method

```
public class globalvariable {
String result="";

public String koneksi(String table,String val_idat){
    InputStream isr= null;
    String hasil="";
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://angkot.esy.es/" + table + "?" + val_idat );
        HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        isr=entity.getContent();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        hasil=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception ex){
            hasil=ex.toString();        
    }
    return hasil;

}
```

}

Comment: what is in line MainActivity.java:241

Comment: ` jArray= new JSONArray(objek); ` objek is result to get string from url @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: post your `koneksi` method

Comment: Add the following line to your code before calling `new JSONArray`...  `Log.d("LoadViewTask", objek);` - what does that print.  Chances are high it's not a valid JSON array string.

Comment: @selbie there is result.

Comment: Please post that string.  Or, just paste the log result of printing `objek` into http://jslint.org .  That site will tell you if your json is valid or not.