# GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 516K, 9% free 9855K/10759K

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I have a class `HandleJson` that have a method `QuestionDone` like below:

```
public class HandleJSON {

    public AtomicBoolean QuestionDone(final String params) {
        final AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String urlParameters = params; 
                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/question_done");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(50000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    // conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                    // "GYUserAgentAndroid");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // conn.setUseCaches (false);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn
                            .getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    System.out.println("Before url.openStream()");
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();// .openStream();
                    System.out.println("After url.openStream()");
                    String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
                    data = data.replace("\"", "").trim();
                    String temp = "";
                    temp = data.substring(0, data.indexOf(" "));
                    if (temp.equals("Thanks"))
                        b.set(true);
                    else
                        b.set(false);
                    readAndParseJSON(data);
                    stream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b.get();
        return b;
    }

}
```

And I am calling this method from my activity through a button like below:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        GetQuestionAndAnswerList {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);


btn_parentDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_parentDone);
        btn_parentDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AtomicBoolean res;

                 concat_str = "abc";
                res = obj.QuestionDone(concat_str);
            }
        });
}
}
```

But I am getting below `error or exception` at this line `res = obj.QuestionDone(concat_str);`:

```
12-15 09:49:25.486: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 516K, 9% free 9855K/10759K, paused 47ms, total 50ms
```

Kindly suggest me, how can I resolve this issue.

waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error, that is dalvik telling you it's reclaiming heap memory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508981/android-gc-for-alloc-freed-6346k-7-free-paused-143ms-total-143ms).